# App Script: How to update spreadsheet cell with live data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In App Script how do you update a cell with data that updates every x amount of time? For example, if a user enters `=myCustomFunction(param,param)` in `A1` I want `A1` to update every 5 minutes.

I know triggers exist but I don't think they completely fulfill what I need. If I enter `=myCustomFunction(param,param)` in `B1` and create a trigger in app script will it always write to `B1`? When I delete the function will the trigger also be deleted (I think the answer is no)?

Any knowledge sharing on the subject would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When using [`Time-driven triggers`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers), the function is executed by the trigger but not the custom function in a cell. You probably need to set the parameters in your script. Please clarify your question.

Comment: @idfurw what do you mean by "set parameters in your script"? You can see the answer below which answered the question correctly however the implementations comes with other issues I mentioned in the comment below the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The rule of thumb is that a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) will only get called to recalculate its results when its parameters change.

This behavior is a side effect of the [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) used by Google Sheets to cache the return values of functions. Its purpose is to improve spreadsheet performance. As long as a function's parameters remain the same, it will return the cached result without recalculating it.

The standard recipe to make the function recalculate is to add a `dummy` parameter that *does* get changed. Your formulas are currently like `=myCustomFunction(param, param)` and you can add a dummy parameter by using `=myCustomFunction(param, param, dummy)`. The dummy parameter should refer to a cell that gets updated with new values every now and then.

Your custom function does not need to actually use the dummy parameter — its mere presence is enough to avoid the memoization effect. The custom function will get called every time the value in the dummy cell changes, which is not a perfect solution, but it is usually good enough for most needs. You can increment the value in dummy cell manually, or use another function that runs on a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) to increment it say every five minutes.

Here is an example of a simple function to increment a dummy cell:

```js
/**
* Increments an integer in a cell.
*/
function incrementCell() {
  const cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('Sheet1!A1');
  cell.setValue((Number(cell.getValue()) || 0) + 1);
}
```

Comment: This makes me wonder how something like the Google Finance function works for price data because it doesn't have a dummy parameter like you mentioned. I've used that method before in another scenario and it makes things really slow when you don't know where the cell you're looking to change will be on the sheet.

Comment: The `googlefinance()` function is a built-in function rather than a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions).