# Make a logger based on ImportJSON output, triggered per minute

Tags: google-sheets

I am making a Google Spreadsheets that logs everytime the output of the formula that uses ImportJSON. The outcome of the picture should be comparible to this image:

[image]

Now, to give some insight, I know I can use a trigger to call a function every minute and "log" the outcome, although I am overthinking the code in Google Appscript presumably.

Context:
In **A1** there is a parameter, used to determine the link it gets its information for with the formula in **A2**

```
=IF(A1 = "", "", ImportJSON("https://example.com/api/public/users?name=" & A1, "/online","noHeaders"))
```

Obviously the above is an example URL so don't expect to extract data (though my website uses API).

As said, I am overthinking probably, so please do help me out. I am not the best in Appscript.
Could someone suggest a code that would work the way it is discribed? I don't get much further then a line that puts every new outcome in a new row, but the actual code is unknown to me and other posts on Stackoverflow did not give much info or was tailored to Python etc.

Destination Tab is called **Data**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Sheet.appendRow()`, like this:

```js
function logDataA2() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sourceCell = ss.getRange('Sheet1!A2');
  const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  targetSheet.appendRow([new Date(), sourceCell.getValue());
}
```

See [Sheet.appendRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object)).

Comment: Hi @doubleunary , this gives a lot of errors. Oct 28, 2023, 7:42:53 PM Error ReferenceError: cell is not defined
    at logDataA2(Check:5:26)
In addition, this doesn't log anything timewise, can you advise?

Comment: In addition (maybe I am failing to understand) the ImportJSON is not refreshed with every trigger (per minute set.) wouldn't this have to be implemented in the code too?

Comment: Fixed the typo in the code. To answer your new question, the usual way to avoid memoization and force a custom function to refresh is to add an additional [dummy parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75082154/13045193) that points to a cell that is updated regularly through a script. However, since you are already using a script, you may want to call `ImportJSON()` directly from your code rather than using a formula to call it as a custom function. Ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). Post a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead.

Comment: Can you also advise on the bit where I asked in my post to also log the time, not just the value of the outcome?

Comment: Edited the answer to add a timestamp. See [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) and [Clean Code JavaScript](https://github.com/ryanmcdermott/clean-code-javascript).