# Google Sheets Appscript: implement dummy parameter to ImportJSON script

Tags: google-sheets

I am making a spreadsheet that logs the outcome of ImportJSON data every minute.
The logging itself is done and works just fine, although I need to think about a dummy parameter in the ImportJSON script, implement this in my formula so that is refreshes every minute.
[See this link for my previous question related to this project.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77380235/make-a-logger-based-on-importjson-output-triggered-per-minute)

Now that the logger works, I need to make a dummy parameter in my ImportJSON script.

```
=IF(A1 = "", "", ImportJSON("https://example.com/api/public/users?name=" & A1, "/online","noHeaders"))
```

The above formula is used to call upon the function.
Good to know;

**A1** contains a name/identifier
**A2** contains the formula

In the standard ImportJSON script found [here](https://gist.github.com/paulgambill/cacd19da95a1421d3164) how do I implement a dummy value, so that my ImportJSON data will be refreshed every minute? [This article containing info on dummy parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75079921/app-script-how-to-update-spreadsheet-cell-with-live-data/75082154#75082154) make sense, though I have no knowledge yet about actually implementing this in a ImportJSON script. The question that follows here, is how to alter the ImportJSON script and formula to refresh every minute?

Answer (score 1):

By adding another parameter to the formula above:

```
=IF(A1 = "", "", ImportJSON("https://example.com/api/public/users?name=" & A1, "/online","noHeaders",B1))
```

It will use B1 as the changing parameter that gets increased every minute with a trigger function.